# Calling $this->forward() results in blank page (but no error)

Tags: php, symfony1, forward

I try to use forward in my action class after a validation back to my action in special cases.

This works in another part of my application.

```
$this->forward('mymodul', 'actionx');
```

But when I execute this Action I only receive a blank page; in the symfony log is a forward message to my action the last entry.

No error on screen nor in my apache logs.

When I use Redirect it works, but I lose all my request parameters.

```
$this->redirect('mymodul/actionx');
```

Has anyone any suggestions?

Comment: Firebug gives me a "500 Internal Server Error" as answer! But I can't find any message in the logs.

Comment: Don't really understand your explanation fully but I'm guessing you're missing a template for "actionx" and the blank page you're seeing is because you're running it in prod mode instead of dev. Make sure you're running dev mode and check the frontend_dev logs. You may need to use return sfView::NONE (if I remember right). For the redirect, you could do $this->redirect('@route?variable=value') and your params won't be lost.

Comment: Thanky You! I just solve it. It was a function redeclare. I use require instead of require_once in both actions.

Comment: @jogep: You should really consider turning on errors while in dev mode.